# Why type casting of a base class to extended class is allowed at compile time in the given scenario?

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation, compiler-errors

I have following scenario.

```
   public class Fruit { 
   public Fruit() {
    System.out.println("Fruit Constructor");
    }

    public String callSuperApple() {
     return "super fruit";
     }
   }


   public class Apple extends Fruit{
     private String color;

     public String callSuperApple() {
     return "super fruit";
     }    
   }
```

And some third class:

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String color;

    public String callSuperApple() {
      return "fruit";
     }
   }
```

Now main method's implementation:

```
public class MainClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fruit fruit= new Fruit ();
    String string = (String)((Apple)fruit).callSuperApple();//line 3
    System.out.println(string);
}
}
```

Here we have exception at the run time but not compile time error.

But when the line 3 is changed to

```
String string = (String)((SomeClass)fruit).callSuperApple();
```

It throws a compile time error. Also the method `callSuperApple()` is implemented in `SomeClass` and `Fruit`.

Now, `Apple` is a type of `Fruit` but we are able to reverse typecast `fruit` to `Apple`. TypeCasting `Apple` to `Fruit` makes sense but not the reverse. Why is this allowed at compile time and with `SomeClass` this is caught at the compile time only?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Casting is always allowed.</s>  You are basically telling the compiler that it's really *this* type.  The JVM will still catch an error at runtime with a `ClassCastException`.

However, the compiler error is because there is no `callSuperApple` method in the `SomeClass` class.  The cast is allowed, but the message is on the method not existing in the class to which you casted `fruit` -- `SomeClass`.

**Addition**

Now, with the change in the question, there *is* a `callSuperApple` method in `SomeClass`.  Now, the compiler error is `error: inconvertible types`, because the compiler knows that neither class can be converted to the other, because neither is a superclass of the other, directly or indirectly.  A `SomeClass` isn't a `Fruit`, and a `Fruit` isn't a `SomeClass`.

You would get the same error with:

```
Number n2 = (Number) "blah";
```

because neither `Number` and `String` aren't superclasses of each other.

Comment: The method has been implemented in the SomeClass and in Fruit (everywhere possible), but still I have error. Please see the edits. Thanks

Comment: Cannot cast from Fruit to SomeClass

Comment: @NihalSharma I've added to my answer.

Comment: So does the compiler consider this neither thing? Should not there be a one direction which is right/wrong for the compiler? Just wondering.

Comment: If it's possible for the cast to succeed, then the compiler will allow it.  If it's impossible, then it's a compiler error.

Comment: Casting is not always allowed. If the compiler can tell that the cast is invalid it will give a error.

Comment: @EJP I forgot to remove that opening sentence when I edited it the first time!  Updated.

Comment: "The cast is allowed, but the message is on the method not existing in the class to which you casted fruit -- SomeClass." - I think this is not true. Please check the same. I have the method everywhere possible. I think there is some other reason for it.